# Writing real linear map in terms of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the following statement but am clueless where to begin:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$T \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$

Then $ \exists \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C} $ such that $T(z)=\lambda z + \mu \bar{z}$

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda (x+yi)+\mu (x-yi)=(ax+by)+(cx+dy)i$

Equating coefficients of $x$ and $y$,

$\left \{
   \begin{array}{ccc}
     \lambda+\mu &=& a+ci \\
     \lambda i-\mu i &=& b+di 
   \end{array}
 \right.$

$\implies \left(
   \begin{array}{c}
     \lambda \\
     \mu
   \end{array}
 \right)=
 \left(
   \begin{array}{c}
     \frac{a+d}{2}+\frac{c-b}{2}i \\
     \frac{a-d}{2}+\frac{b+c}{2}i
   \end{array}
 \right)$

Comment: Should $\frac{c+d}{2}$ and $\frac{c-d}{2}$ be the other way round?

Comment: Also, if $\mu \not= 0$ then why is the function not complex linear?

Comment: Correcting, be patient

Comment: No worries. I was thinking that $\mu \not= 0$ isn't complex linear because we can't express it as multiplication by a complex number but wasn't sure if that was sufficient. Thanks again